# debian: cannot change password

Tags: debian, password, kerberos, pam

As the root user, I can change the password:

```
hussie:/home/claudiu# passwd
Enter new password:
Retype new password:
passwd: password updated successfully
```

As a non-root user I cannot:

```
claudiu@hussie:~$ passwd
Current Kerberos password:
passwd: User not known to the underlying authentication module
passwd: password unchanged
```

I also can't change another user's password from root:

```
hussie:/home/claudiu# passwd claudiu
Current Kerberos password:
passwd: User not known to the underlying authentication module
passwd: password unchanged
```

Googling the issue suggests using `pwconv` and `pwunconv`, but I don't have those and don't know where to find them:

```
claudiu@hussie:~$ pwconv
-bash: pwconv: command not found
claudiu@hussie:~$ pwunconv
-bash: pwunconv: command not found
claudiu@hussie:~$ sudo apt-get install pwconv
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package pwconv
claudiu@hussie:~$ sudo apt-get install pwunconv
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package pwunconv
```

What do I do?

Comment: Dude, If this is on that compromised system, then you need to nuke it.  It is too late to mess around with passwords.

Comment: @Zoredache: it is, and i will, but i can't disconnect it from the internet (renting the server, don't have it physically) so I at least want to change the passwords for now.

Comment: If what Zordache says is true (the system is compromise) - and there's kerberos setup, look for the kerberos pam config file to find out where the hell it's pointing ...

Comment: You realise that one of the first things a hacker will do is replace passwd with a trojanized version?  Even if you do change he password there are most certainly backdoors.  Anyway, you could just edit the passwd/shadow files directly.  It probably will not help though.

Comment: I think using krb5 was their way of 'trojanizing' the passwd; doing it this way is actually smarter from their perspective.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have another authentication method (kerberos) in use than a standard linux account - chances are the pam module is unable to write/update passwords. Doing so from root confuses the module because root is truly a local account and not in the other service's user list.

Look for some hints to what pam modules are in use look in `/etc/pam.conf` and in the dir: `/etc/pam.d` - `/etc/nsswitch.conf` may also provide hints, but debian uses `compat` which doesn't really help in specifying what is in use obviously.

If kerberos is indeed in use, you can't update the password using `passwd`

Comment: `pam.conf` is empty, and `/etc/pam.d/passwd/` just uses the `common-password` file, which has: `pam_krb5.so minimum_uid=1000` as the first line, the next one being `pam_unix.so obscure use_authtok try_first_pass sha512`. where do I go from here? (Note this is how the system was installed, i didn't modify anything - could never change the user passwd)

Comment: How about `/etc/pam.d/common-auth` (Possibly `/etc/pamd.d/common-account` as well) ?

Comment: Ah, ok, you've got pam_krb5 enabled (kerberos) which correlates directly with the error message. This server is setup to use kerberos authentication - which is completely key based - so you're really not going to change the password from the 'passwd' command but update the key pair with the kerberos server

Comment: -UNLESS- kerberos is completely irrelevant and there's absolutely no way it should be in use, then just rem that line out - but you'd better be damn sure you can get in with a standard linux account and change that file if something goes wrong ;)

Comment: hmm i have no `kpasswd` command or `/usr/krb5` directory.. is that a safe bet it is irrelevant?

Comment: ah great, i used `pam-auth-update` command and disabled Kerberos authentication, and now `passwd` works. thanks very much!!

Comment: Switch off kerberos, run `passwd` then switch kerberos back on again as described [here](https://serverfault.com/a/549601/423383)

Answer (score 13):

Run "pam-auth-update"

It'll prompt.

Debian has been really annoying and added kerberos by default during apt-get upgrade(s).